# ios uisegmentedcontrol with different sizes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, size, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I wish use a uisegmentedcontrol in my app with 3 segments but not with the same size, the first and the third smaller than the second...
is this possible? how can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
[yourSegmentedController widthForSegmentAtIndex:indexOfSegmentYouWantToChange];
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Can be better to do:

```
[yourSegmentedController sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Would you need to subclass UISegmented control first?

Comment: No. At least for the SDK I used at that time.

Answer (score 5):

This sure works:

```
[self.mySegmentedControl setWidth:30.f forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code it helped me:

```
segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```